# Need DIV to disappear when a separate DIV is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, slider, hide

I'm building a site with a home page that has a DIV positioned (fixed) at the top. When the navigation links at the bottom are clicked, a slide activates which jquery to slide up from the bottom. (excuse the messy content for now). What I'd like to happen is whenever a slide is activated and comes up, the top header DIV disappears. (and then re-appears when the slide goes down). Is this possible?

There's a lot of code so I'll just link directly [here](http://www.gp3designs.com/griffin)

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: you mean the div with an id "mast_head" should be disappeared when content is slide up from the bottom?

Comment: Hm, I don't see a button to go back to the main page anyway.

Comment: yes, DG3, the mast_head.

Comment: @fritzfromlondon, then why'd you bother replying. I'm not asking to bother you. I'm asking an open forum because I'm new at this. Move on to the next person you can talk down to.

Comment: You get better answer if you ask better questions. A lot of people just come to SO hoping that others do their work for them. If you create a simplified version of your problem, you are more likely to get a useful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your below jquery function, add $("#mast_head").hide()

```
$('#menu li a').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $("#mast_head").hide()
   animateSlider(this.hash);
 });
```

Comment: it means select an element whose id is "mast_head". It is equivalent to javascript's document.getElementById("mast_head"). Read more about jquery selectors

Comment: I am talking about animateSlider(this.hash);
 actually this.hash

Comment: @refhat, sorry misread your comment. this.hash is some code of OP. I got it from the website he posted.

Comment: @DG3 that works great to make it disappear. Is there a way to make it reappear when no slide is up?

Comment: can you post the link to your website?

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#div1').click(function(){
        $('#div2').hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2" onclick="$('#div1').hide()"></div>
```

or, instead of onclick, just do..

```
$('#div2').on('click', function(){($'#div1').hide();});
```

Comment: yep, its obtrusive, but it shows the solution...how he implements the onclick is up to him